# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after set plugin = ''

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.7

I have MySQL 5.7 installed and wanted to enable passwordless login for root.

So I executed

```
mysql> update mysql.user set plugin='' where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Now I am not able to login anymore as root. Neither with the password nor without the password. I receive the following errors respectively:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I read about solutions using mysqld_safe but I cannot use that since we are using systemd.

Any suggestions? Ideally without restarting mysqld but well ...

---

Also I tried

```
mysqladmin flush-privileges
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up stopping mysqld and did the following

```
systemctl stop mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &

mysql -u root
mysql> update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
mysql>flush privileges;

systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

And it's working again

Answer (score 1):

"*Suggestions?*"

Accckkk! I can't fathom what would compel someone to think that `root` user login with no authentication is a good idea.

I suggest we reconsider the security implications of a  "passwordless" login for a privileged user. (That would be red flag on a security audit.)  If I absolutely had to implement a passwordless login (because every other possible alternative solution has been ruled out), I would ONLY do that for a user that had very strictly *limited* privileges.

---

To implement a "no password" login in MySQL, we can use `'native_mysql_password'` for `plugin`, and use an empty string `''` for `password`.

(I'm not aware of any reason we would want to set `plugin` to be empty string.)

Comment: Not sure why this answer deserved a downvote. The only question that was asked was "*Any suggestions?*" (As far as OP not being able to connect, I think that has to do with plugin being set to an empty string, when what we need for a "no password" login is `plugin='native_mysql_password'` and `password=''`, which I made as one of the *suggestions* in this answer.